# Spark : Pivot with multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have the following `json` file that I am reading in Spark:

```
{"id" : "123", "category" : "A"}
{"id" : "456", "category" : "B"}
{"id" : "567", "category" : "C"}
{"id" : "678", "category" : "D"}
{"id" : "789", "category" : "E"}
{"id" : "123", "category" : "B"}
{"id" : "123", "category" : "C"}
```

I want to `pivot` it to generate mxn matrix of categories. Below is my code:

```
val df = spark.read.json("test.json")
val pivots = df.groupBy("category").pivot("category").count()
pivots.show()
```

This generates the following output:

```
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+
|category|   A|   B|   C|   D|   E|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+
|       E|null|null|null|null|   1|
|       B|null|   2|null|null|null|
|       D|null|null|null|   1|null|
|       C|null|null|   2|null|null|
|       A|   1|null|null|null|null|
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

What I really want to do is, to pivot by `id` and show the counts in this matrix. E.g. `id` '123' is mapped to categories `A`, `B` and `C`, so I want the above matrix to show `1` value for `A-A`, `A-B` and `A-C` (and vice versa), currently, it's only showing `1` value for `A-A`.

I changed the code to `group by` 'id' but that results in `id` values in first column whereas I want categories.

Is there any way I can do this (maybe using a completely different approach)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist rename the columns and apply self-join:

```
val leftRight = df
  .withColumnRenamed("category", "left")
  .join(df.withColumnRenamed("category", "right"), Seq("id"))
```

to get co-occurrences for each id. Next apply `crosstab`:

```
leftRight.stat.crosstab("left", "right")
```

to aggregate data across all ids. The result is:

```
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|left_right|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|         E|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
|         A|  1|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|         B|  1|  2|  1|  0|  0|
|         C|  1|  1|  2|  0|  0|
|         D|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
```